# Question about spacing \hspace and \vspace

Tags: spacing

I have been using `\hspace` and `\vspace` in my latex documents lately. I was surprised when `\hspace{1em}` didn't work and found out that I needed to use `\hspace*{1em}` to force latex to put the space requested.
My question is why does latex sometimes ignores `\hspace{1em}`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

When TeX breaks a line it discards white space (glue) that would come at the start of a line. This is why you get an inter-word space *or* a line break between words, not both. So if the `\hspace` comes at the beginning of a line the space gets added by LaTeX but discarded by the TeX paragraph breaker. The `*` version arranges to put a non-discardable invisible item in fromt of the space so the space is never first thing on the line (even though it looks like it is). `\vspace` and `\vspace*` the same with respect to vertical space discarded at a *page* break.

Comment: so if I put `\vspace` at the end of the previous line, it'll behave the same as `\vspace*`? Thanks for your explanation

Comment: did you mean `\vspace` there or `\hspace`. If you use `\vspace(*)` mid-paragraph then after the paragraph is broken in to lines tex will insert vertical space after the line that contained the `vspace`. Then later if the page breaker breaks the page between those lines the space will be discarded unless the * form was used.

Comment: Ok, I get it :-)