# \hspace vs. \hspace*

Tags: spacing, starred-version

After trying both commands, I noticed that `\hspace*` opposite to `\hspace` will insert a space over the end of the line.

So I was wondering if someone could explain how that works and also when to use either command.

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30456/do-all-starred-commands-have-anything-in-common and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37343/how-can-i-force-a-hspace-at-the-beginning-of-a-line and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33370/adding-vertical-space-at-the-start-of-a-page

Comment: another related, and more to the point: [Question about spacing \hspace and \vspace](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64043/)

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Spaces (glues and kerns) disappear after line breaks by rule; by the same rule, line breaks can happen only at the "left edge" of a space. Moreover, if one says `\hspace{1cm}\hspace{1cm}`, the first `\hspace` is a feasible break point, but *not* the second one.

This is how TeX attains alignment to the left margin for normal and ragged right paragraphs (ragged left uses a different feature).

More precisely, a glue (`\hspace`) can be chosen as break point only if it is preceded by a *non discardable* item (most commonly a character or a rule). Among discardable items are *penalties*.

In some cases one wants to have spaces that don't disappear at line breaks: for instance blanks that should filled by hand in an exercise. Thus LaTeX provides the `\hspace*` variant.

When `\hspace*{1cm}` is called, LaTeX uses the internal command `\@hspacer`, which does

```
\vrule width 0pt \nobreak \hskip 1cm \hskip 0pt plus 0pt minus 0pt
```

1. `\vrule width 0pt` places an invisible object that takes up no space;
2. `\nobreak` sets a point where line breaking is impossible, by issuing a very large penalty;
3. `\hskip 1cm` cannot be used as a break point, because it is preceded by a discardable item (the penalty);
4. `\hskip 0pt plus 0pt minus 0pt` is inserted to avoid possible problems due to the peculiar syntax of the primitive `\hskip`; it won't be a feasible break point, because it's preceded by a discardable item;
5. in case `\par` follows, then that last glob of glue is removed, but not the main one.

Thus `\hspace*{1cm}` forms, so to speak, an indivisible unit that will never be taken as a break point, nor will disappear at line breaks.

A consequence of this rules is that a space *after* `\hspace*{1cm}` cannot be used as break point.

Suppose we want to define a `\blank` macro for leaving space to be later filled in by hand:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\blank}[1]{\hspace*{#1}}

\begin{document}

\parbox{4cm}{
 Some text to see what's going on: \blank{2cm} and \blank{3cm} with text after them
}

\end{document}
```

The result will be

[image]

(where the rules represent the `\hspace*{...}` commands; they won't be printed by this command, I used them just to show the effect). You can see that the space after `\blank{...}` is not used as break point.

With a different definition, the blanks *can* appear at the end of the line:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\blank}[1]{\hspace*{#1}\linebreak[0]}

\begin{document}

\parbox{4cm}{
 Some text to see what's going on: \blank{2cm} and \blank{3cm} with text after them
}

\end{document}
```

will result in

[image]

Of course the typesetting here is suboptimal, but the point is to show how the thing works.

The `\linebreak[0]` command just inserts a feasible break point, without stating any particular preference for it.

---

For the interested readers, the "rule" effect for showing `\hspace*` has been obtained with the following trick:

```
\let\TeXhskip\hskip
\def\hskip{\leaders\hrule\TeXhskip}
```