# Create an indent in an algorithm (without using the algorithm environment)

Tags: indentation, algorithms

So I'm trying to create an indent in an algorithm, but I'm not familiar with the \begin{algorithm} environment, so I would just like to do it in a math environment. I'm trying to create an indent, but the code below doesn't seem to work. Please help?

```
 \documentclass{article}  
 \begin{document}  
 $S=\emptyset;\ i=k=1;\ N[j]=Z[j]=S^*[j]=COMP[j]=0;\ j=1,2,...,11\\   
 j=1.\\  
 \hspace{4ex} VISIT(1)....$  
 \end{document}
```

Comment: You have to use `\hspace*` (starred version). Anyway the result is awful...

Comment: If you tell us what you're trying to achieve, probably an answer using algorithm-specific packages will appear...

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about the starred version. And believe it or not, the result is exactly what I wanted, just a small indent, going only 2 layers deep.

Comment: So the question can be closed as a duplicate of this one? http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/89082/27635

Comment: You are setting mult-letter identifiers such as VISIT in math italic, which is all wrong you need \mathrm or \mathit, similarly ... should be \ldots