# I need to shift multiline equations as per attached image

Tags: equations, multline

But adding a \hspace doesn't even work and the equations are left justified.  Can someone assist me please?  Example code is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{multline}
\begin{split}
[1,2,\ldots,t,\ldots,t+h]\;,\\
[2,\ldots,t+1,\ldots,t+h+1]\;,\\
\vdots\\
[N,\ldots,t+N,\ldots,t+h+N]\;,
\end{split}
 \end{multline}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Use `\hspace*` rather than `\hspace`.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! See [\hspace vs. \hspace*](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/89082/124842)

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't seem to work in the equation environment.

Comment: If you remove the `split`, do you get what you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple way to achieve this is to place each line in the second column of an `aligned` environment, which is itself placed inside an equation environment. Then, the whole structure is centred, with each line beginning at the same point. You can create the necessary indentations using `\hspace`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{equation} 
\begin{aligned}
&[1,2,\ldots,t,\ldots,t+h],\\  
&\hspace{50pt}[2,\ldots,t+1,\ldots,t+h+1],\\
&\hspace{130pt}\vdots\\    
&\hspace{100pt}[N,\ldots,t+N,\ldots,t+h+N],   
\end{aligned}    
\end{equation}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that it is possible to use `\hspace` here because the space is not the first item on the line (otherwise you would need `\hspace*` to prevent the space being discarded). Of course, you will need to adjust the size of the `\hspace`s manually, so if you need a lot of similar constructions then a more sophisticated approach may be needed.

Incidentally, I don't think you can use `split` inside a `multline` (as in your example); if you try you will get the warning

> Package amsmath Warning: Cannot use `split' here; (amsmath)
>
>   trying to recover with`aligned' on input line 19.