# What is the difference between \vspace{\fill} and \vfill

Tags: spacing, macros

What is the difference between `\vspace{\fill}` and `\vfill`?  What about the starred version of them?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

`\vspace{\fill}` and `\vfill` are not exactly equivalent. They are if they appear *between* paragraphs, but not if they appear *in* a paragraph.

- `\vspace{\fill}` in a paragraph will add the filling vertical space below the line in which it eventually appears;
- `\vfill` *ends* the paragraph at the spot and adds the filling vertical space.

Indeed `\vfill` is a TeX primitive, while `\vspace` is defined by LaTeX to have the described effect when found in a paragraph. In vertical mode, `\vspace{<glue>}` is equivalent to the primitive `\vskip<glue>`. See [\vspace vs. \vskip](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30062/vspace-vs-vskip) for more information.

There is *no* `\vfill*`, if you're asking about this. The difference between `\vspace{<glue>}` and `\vspace*{<glue>}` is that the latter is not discarded at page breaks. See [Question about spacing \hspace and \vspace](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64043/question-about-spacing-hspace-and-vspace).

Comment: I didn't know there is no `\vfill*`, but I was also interested about `\vspace*{\vfill}`

Comment: @MarioS.E. You probably mean `\vspace*{\fill}`: it exists and has a similar behaviour to `\vspace*`, only using `\fill` as the length for the vertical space. One of the uses is to put a paragraph at the bottom of the page, e.g. a colophon, when there is no other text on the page (hence the use of the `*`).