# Align shaded box to bottom of page

Tags: framed

I have a page that has a table at the top and a shaded box at the bottom. How to get the shaded box to align with the bottom of the page frame? I've tried `\vfill`, but that doesn't seem to work. My code is as follows:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[x11names,table]{xcolor}
\colorlet{shadecolor}{LavenderBlush2}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[t!]
\caption{Hello World!}
\begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{|c|X|c|}\hline
    A & B & C \\\hline
    D & E & F \\\hline
    G & H & I \\\hline
    J & K & L \\\hline
    M & N & O \\\hline
    P & Q & R \\\hline
    S & T & U \\\hline
    V & W & X \\\hline
    Y & Z &   \\\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\par
\vfill
\begin{shaded*}
\noindent\blindtext\par
\blindtext\par
\blindtext
\end{shaded*}
\end{document}
```

This currently produces the following output:
[image]

**Edit:**
It has been suggested that I use `\vspace*{\fill}` instead. That does lower the box, but it still doesn't quite align with the page frame.
[image]

Comment: Use `\vspace*{\fill}` instead.

Comment: The box lowers down, but still doesn't quite align with the page frame (there's still a gap of about 0,5 - 1,0 cm)

Comment: The space is added by the environment.  Use  `\OuterFrameSep` to changed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [difference between \vspace{\fill} and \vfill](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/118805/161015)

> - `\vspace{\fill}` in a paragraph will add the filling vertical space    below the line in which it eventually appears;
> - `\vfill` ends the paragraph at the spot and adds the filling vertical    space.

You can use `\vspace{\fill}` or  `\ \vfill` . The latter starts a paragraph with a (empty) space.

[image: a]

Set `\OuterFrameSep`= 0pt to remove the vertical space before and after the framed environment. It defaults  to `\topsep`.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[x11names,table]{xcolor}
\colorlet{shadecolor}{LavenderBlush2}
\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[t!]
        \caption{Hello World!}
        \begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{|c|X|c|}\hline
            A & B & C \\\hline
            D & E & F \\\hline
            G & H & I \\\hline
            J & K & L \\\hline
            M & N & O \\\hline
            P & Q & R \\\hline
            S & T & U \\\hline
            V & W & X \\\hline
            Y & Z &   \\\hline
        \end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
%% \ \vfill
\vspace*{\fill}% added <<<<<<<<<<<
\setlength{\OuterFrameSep}{0pt}% added <<<<<<<<<<<
    \begin{shaded*}
        \noindent\blindtext\par
        \blindtext\par
        \blindtext
    \end{shaded*}
\end{document}
```