# Align shaded box to top of page

Tags: framed

I have a page that has a shaded box at the top. How do I get the shaded box to align with the top of the page frame? There's a bit of a gap. My code:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{framed}
\colorlet{shadecolor}{LavenderBlush2}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\setlength{\OuterFrameSep}{0pt}
\begin{shaded*}
\lipsum[1]
\end{shaded*}
\vfill
\begin{shaded*}
\lipsum[1]
\end{shaded*}
\end{document}
```

results in
[image]

In another question ([Align shaded box to bottom of page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/639603/align-shaded-box-to-bottom-of-page)), it has been suggested to set `OuterFrameSep` to 0 in order to remove the vertical space before and after the framed environment. That does seem to work for after the framed environment, but not before.

Comment: You can add `\leavevmode\vspace{-3.75ex}` just before `\begin{shaded*}` (found by trial and error).

Comment: It's caused by `\topskip` (initially `10pt`). Setting it to `0pt` works, but a zero `\topskip` is not ideal for pages that starts with textual content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following, it may work for you too:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{framed}
\colorlet{shadecolor}{LavenderBlush2}
\setlength{\OuterFrameSep}{0pt}

\usepackage{etoolbox}                           % <---
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{shaded*}{\topskip=0pt}  % <---
\AfterEndEnvironment{shaded*}{\topskip=10pt}    % <---
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%---------------- Show page layout. Don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
\begin{shaded*}
\lipsum[1]
\end{shaded*}

\vfill
\begin{shaded*}
\lipsum[1]
\end{shaded*}
\clearpage
\begin{figure}[ht]
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
\end{figure}
\section{title}\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is to use the package `tcolorbox`. Here is a version that gives you a lot of control about essentially everything:

```latex
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\colorlet{shadecolor}{LavenderBlush2}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tcolorbox}[boxrule=0mm, boxsep=0mm, sharp corners, colback=shadecolor]
        \lipsum[1]
    \end{tcolorbox}
    \vfill
    \begin{tcolorbox}[boxrule=0mm, boxsep=0mm, 
                      after skip=0pt,  % this removes some extra space at the bottom
                      bottom=2ex, top=2ex, right=2ex, left=2ex,  % 'padding' between text and border
                      sharp corners, colback=shadecolor]
        \lipsum[1]
    \end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```