# Inserting half a \vfill

Tags: xetex, vertical-spacing, vspace

If a page contains multiple `\vfill`s, the space space is distributed equally between them.  That means if you want one-third of the available space above some text and two-thirds below it, you can put `\vfill` above and `\vfill\vfill` below.

However at the moment our typesetting system (a heavily hacked up version of Pandoc) is hard-coding a single `\vfill` below the text.  (This isn't being generated by a macro which could be altered with `\patchcmd` – it appears literally in the TeX source.)  Is there anything I can do to insert a half \vfill above the text?  [`\vfill` is nearly equivalent to `\vspace{\fill}`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/118802/what-is-the-difference-between-vspace-fill-and-vfill), so I hoped I might be able to do `\vspace{0.5\fill}` (possibly with `\includepackage{calc}`), but this seems not to work.  Is there a way of achieving this?

MWE for illustration:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\begin{document}
Top of page
\vfill  % Needs changing to be a 0.5\vfill

% The code from here on cannot be altered
This should be one-third of the way down the page
\vfill\clearpage
\end{document}
```

(I know I could redefine `\vfill` to be `\vfill\vfill`, but I was hoping for a better solution.)

In case it's relevant, I'm using XeLaTeX.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\begin{document}
Top of page

\vspace{0pt plus 0.5fill} 

This should be one-third of the way down the page

\vfill

\clearpage
\end{document}
```

[image]