# center align 2x2 plot of subfigures

Tags: floats, horizontal-alignment, margins, align, subfloats

I've got a 2x2 plot of subfigures that is too wide to fit within the margins of a page. Latex left aligns it and the right hand side goes off the page. I would like to center align the whole thing without making the width of the subplots any smaller.

[image: This is what it looks like].

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subfig} 

\captionsetup{width=.75\textwidth,skip=0.3cm,within=none}

\begin{document}



\begin{figure}%[!hbt]

\begin{center}

\subfloat[US]{\includegraphics[width=100mm]{Results/Fig/USslope.pdf}} 
\subfloat[Japan]{\includegraphics[width=100mm]{Results/Fig/JPNslope.pdf}} \\

\noindent 
\subfloat[UK]{\includegraphics[width=100mm]{Results/Fig/UKslope.pdf}}
\subfloat[Italy]{\includegraphics[width=100mm]{Results/Fig/Itslope.pdf}}


\caption[caption]{Slope Components} 
\end{center}

\end{figure}
\end{document}





\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! See if http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2319/center-flow-chart-horizontally, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16582/center-figure-that-is-wider-than-textwidth or http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39435/how-can-i-center-a-too-wide-table help. Also note that you should generally use `\centering` rather than the `center` environment in `figure`s, see [Should I use center or centering for figures and tables?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2651)

Comment: Thanks for the tips Torbjørn!
Adding \hspace*{-4cm} before \subfloat[US] and \subfloat[UK] worked for me but I don't know why...

\hspace{-4cm} won't work. For some reason it needs the asterisk.

Comment: The unstarred version won't work at the start of lines, see e.g http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64043/question-about-spacing-hspace-and-vspace and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89082/hspace-vs-hspace

Comment: Why not use relative measures for the widths? Use `width=0.45\textwidth` instead of `width=100mm` and at the end of first subfloat you can add `\hfill`.